# Как инициализировать одномерный массив без цикла?

Tags: c++

Я хочу инициализировать массив единицами, но инициализирует только одно значение единицей остальное нулями.

я делаю так

```
int size = 5;
int array_asfkf[size]{1};
```

знаю можно через цикл вот так

```
int size = 5;
int array_asfkf[size]{};
for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
            array_asfkf[i] = 1;
        }
```

Но хочется что то упрощенное.

Comment: Ну так и инициализировать - `int array_asfkf[size] = {1,1,1,1,1};`

Comment: @Harry я не знаю какой размер будет в будущем у  size, точнее знаю, просто я его постоянно менять буду, мне неудобно.

Comment: В gcc (но это C, а не С++) очень просто -- `int a[N] = {[0 ... N - 1] = 1};`. В с++ придется написать что-то типа этого -- `std::array<int, N> a; a.fill(1);`

Comment: @avp да не очень понятно, походу придется код переписывать что бы вместо 1 использовал 0

Comment: @alpokon, в fill() можно использовать переменную, а не константу (а проще и надежней написать свою функцию инициализации (причем, это явно быстрее, чем спрашивать на сайте))

Comment: Ну, `memset` можно использовать. Как по мне, то написать тогда свою функцию создания массива с заполнением единицами и не мучиться... Кстати, раз "постоянно менять будете" — то когда? Во время компиляции он известен? Или уже во время выполнения?

Comment: @Harry да до компиляции все известно

Comment: В любом случае заполнение будет происходить уже во время выполнения, так что с точки зрения эффективности выигрыша нет. С точки зрения краткости кода... терзают меня смутные сомнения, что простенький макрос или функцию написать проще и короче... Да, а чем `vector` не устраивает?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <array>
#include <utility>
#include <cstddef>

template<::std::size_t x_size, ::std::size_t... x_indexes>
[[nodiscard]] auto
Make_Array_Impl(int const value, ::std::index_sequence<x_indexes...>)
{
    return ::std::array<int, x_size>{(static_cast<void>(x_indexes), value) ...};
}

template<::std::size_t x_size>
[[nodiscard]] auto
Make_Array(int const value)
{
    return Make_Array_Impl<x_size>(value, ::std::make_index_sequence<x_size>());
}

#include <cassert>

int main()
{
    auto const items{Make_Array<3>(1)};
    assert(1 == items[0]);
    assert(1 == items[1]);
    assert(1 == items[2]);
    return 0;
}
```

[online compiler](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:29,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:29,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:%27%23include+%3Carray%3E%0A%23include+%3Cutility%3E%0A%23include+%3Ccstddef%3E%0A%0Atemplate%3C::std::size_t+x_size,+::std::size_t...+x_indexes%3E%0A%5B%5Bnodiscard%5D%5D+auto%0AMake_Array_Impl(int+const+value,+::std::index_sequence%3Cx_indexes...%3E)%0A%7B%0A++++return+::std::array%3Cint,+x_size%3E%7B(static_cast%3Cvoid%3E(x_indexes),+value)+...%7D%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Atemplate%3C::std::size_t+x_size%3E%0A%5B%5Bnodiscard%5D%5D+auto%0AMake_Array(int+const+value)%0A%7B%0A++++return+Make_Array_Impl%3Cx_size%3E(value,+::std::make_index_sequence%3Cx_size%3E())%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A%23include+%3Ccassert%3E%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++++auto+const+items%7BMake_Array%3C3%3E(1)%7D%3B%0A++++assert(1+%3D%3D+items%5B0%5D)%3B%0A++++assert(1+%3D%3D+items%5B1%5D)%3B%0A++++assert(1+%3D%3D+items%5B2%5D)%3B%0A++++return+0%3B%0A%7D%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g121,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27--std%3Dc%2B%2B20+-Wall+-Wextra+-Wpedantic%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1,tree:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+gcc+12.1+(C%2B%2B,+Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+gcc+12.1%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+gcc+12.1+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

Comment: Ради такой маленькой инициализации такую функцию добавить, а это нормально будет.
А то скажут мне потом совсем дурак.

Comment: @alpokon Ну если такая инициализация нужная многократно - то нормально, дублирование будет устраняться. В случае динамического массива (`std::vector`) такая функциональность доступна в стандартной библиотеке из коробки.

Comment: Ладно, жалко что других вариантов нету по умолчанию в C++

Comment: Лишнее использование  auto  может и запутать и отвлечь внимание от  использования std::array. Зачем  тогда не делать так, как подсказывал  
'avp'?  И чем хуже простой алгоритм  std::fill(array, array + size, 1) ?